# How can I move loose-fill insulation temporarily?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, ceiling-fan

My current bathroom fan is dead and needs replacement. I tried removing it from the inside of the house, but something is holding it. I'll need to do it from the attic.

The attic is covered with loose-fill insulation. What should I do to temporarily move the insulation while I replace the fan?

Comment: First, check the type of insulation.  If it's cellulose, no problem, just get a big piece of cardboard or shovel or something and move it around.  HOWEVER, if it's stone like, its possibly vermiculite - and old vermiculite was often blended with asbestos.  DO NOT TOUCH IT IN THAT CASE - call in an inspector.

Comment: Here is the link to the US EPA webpage on vermiculite insulation. http://www.epa.gov/asbestos/pubs/verm.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the insulation is safe to be around, use a plastic lawn rake. After years of settling, you can use the same rake to "fluff" up your loose fill insulation to make it more efficient.